# How to implement AutoPlay for image import in c# under windows 10

Tags: c#, windows, winapi

I am trying to implement an AutoPlayHandler that automatically imports pictures to my application (a cloud based storage client similar to i.e. dropbox) when a removable storage is connected to the system.

I have found [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15227425/how-to-implement-autoplay-for-windows-7-8) and [this article on code-project](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/15626/Implement-an-Autoplay-Handler) and did all the code-project article explains but **I can not get my handler to be executed**. Everytime I plug in a device a message box pops explaining that "no program is registered to open this file".

The handler is in the list in control panel and I can select it.

What am I doing wrong or missing?

---

This is my current code:

```
using System;
using System.IO;
using System.Runtime.InteropServices;
using SpikeAutoPlay.AutoPlayOnArrivalHandler;

namespace MyAutoPlay
{
    [ComImport,
    InterfaceType(ComInterfaceType.InterfaceIsIUnknown),
     Guid("00000122-0000-0000-C000-000000000046")]
    public interface IDropTarget
    {
        [PreserveSig]
        int DragEnter(IntPtr pDataObj,               //  IDataObject
                      ulong grfKeyState,             //  DWORD
                      POINTL pt,
                      ref ulong pdwEffect);          //  DWORD*

        [PreserveSig]
        int DragOver(ulong grfKeyState,              //  DWORD
                     POINTL pt,
                     ref ulong pdwEffect);           //  DWORD*

        [PreserveSig]
        int DragLeave();

        [PreserveSig]
        int Drop(IntPtr pDataObj,                    //  IDataObject
                 ulong grfKeyState,                  //  DWORD
                 POINTL pt,
                 ref ulong pdwEffect);               //  DWORD*

    }

    [ComVisible(true), Guid("06D15143-F98C-48D0-AEA8-F0675C103511")]
    public class AutoPlayOnArrivalHandler : IDropTarget
    {        
        public int DragEnter(IntPtr pDataObj,
            ulong grfKeyState,
            POINTL pt,
            ref ulong pdwEffect)
        {
            return 0; // Not needed for autoplay
        }

        public int DragOver(ulong grfKeyState,
            POINTL pt,
            ref ulong pdwEffect)
        {
            return 0; // Not needed for autoplay
        }

        public int DragLeave()
        {
            return 0; // Not needed for autoplay
        }

        public int Drop(IntPtr pDataObj,
            ulong grfKeyState,
            POINTL pt,
            ref ulong pdwEffect)
        {
            File.Create("C:\\temp\\works.txt");

            return 0;
        }
    }
}
```

---

And this are the entries in the registry that I made:

```
HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE
  SOFTWARE
    Microsoft
      Windows
        CurrentVersion
          Explorer
            AutoplayHandlers
              Handlers
                SpikeAutoplay 
                  Action [REG_SZ]= SpikeAutoPlay Action Value
                  DefaultIcon [REG_SZ]= C:\path\to\myApp.ico
                  InvokeProgID [REG_SZ]= MyAutoPlay.AutoPlayOnArrivalHandler
                  InvokeVerb [REG_SZ]= import
                  Provider [REG_SZ]= SpikeAutoPlay Provider Value


HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT
  MyAutoPlay.AutoPlayOnArrivalHandler
    shell
      import
        DropTarget
           ClSID [REG_SZ]= {{06D15143-F98C-48D0-AEA8-F0675C103511}}


HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE
  SOFTWARE
    Microsoft
      Windows
        CurrentVersion
          Explorer
            AutoplayHandlers
              EventHandlers
                ShowPicturesOnArrival
                  SpikeAutoplay [REG_SZ]

HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT
  CLSID
    {06D15143-F98C-48D0-AEA8-F0675C103511}
      InprocServer32
        (Standard) [RES_SZ] = c:\_sources\MyAutoPlayHander\bin\Debug\MyShellExtensions.dll
        ThreadingModel [REG_SZ]= Apartment
```

Comment: I don`t see HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\CLSID\{06D15143-F98C-48D0-AEA8-F0675C103511} in your message.

Comment: OS bitness? Extension bitness?

Comment: The extension is compiled x86 the OS is win10 x64. The registry entries described in my question have been automatically duplicated to the WOW6432Node

Comment: Your extension MUST BE x64 too.

Comment: I double checked that now and I was wrong. My solution platform is x86 but the extension is compiled AnyCPU, sorry. Did you notice my update on the actual error? ("no program is registered to open this file")

Comment: I don`t know what is "AnyCPU" bitness. What the real bitness of MyShellExtensions.dll?

Comment: "AnyCPU" can be understood as "both". However I explicitly compiled it to x64 and that did not fix my problem either.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In case anyone else has this problem. Here is the solution I ended up with:

I completely refrained from my initial idea of implementing IDropTarget. Instead I decided to start an instance of my app and pass just the drive letter of the removable device. The app would then do whatever it needs to do with that information (in my case copy all files of a specific type from the removable device to a specific folder on another drive). Since my app is already making sure that there is only a single instance when it starts this was not a problem to me.

---

### Now here is how that works

A handler needs to be created:

```
HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE
    SOFTWARE
        Microsoft
          Windows
            CurrentVersion
              Explorer
                AutoplayHandlers
                  Handlers
                    SpikeAutoplay
                      Action [REG_SZ]= Import pictures (This value will be shown to the user)
                      DefaultIcon [REG_SZ]= C:\path\to\myApp.ico
                      InvokeProgID [REG_SZ]= MyAutoPlay.AutoPlayOnArrivalHandler
                      InvokeVerb [REG_SZ]= open
                      Provider [REG_SZ]= human readable app name (This value will be shown to the user as well)
```

Now, for the string value given as "InvokeProgID" there must be a key with the exact same value (note that the keys changed from *import* and *dropTarget* to ***open*** and ***command***)

```
HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\HiDrive.AutoPlayOnArrivalHandler
    shell
        open
            command
                (Standard) [REG_SZ] = "C:\Path\To\Your\App.exe" %1 (mind the quotes)
```

The **%1** will pass the drive letter of the media as an argument to your app.

Now, for every event that you want to tread you'll have to add your event handler to the respective sub-key under

```
HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE
  SOFTWARE
    Microsoft
      Windows
        CurrentVersion
          Explorer
            AutoplayHandlers
              EventHandlers
```

For example if you want to handle the "ShowPictureOnArrival" event you'll have to add a new value [REG_SZ] with the name of your event handler ("SpikeAutoplay" in this case) as value. Example:

```
HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE
  SOFTWARE
    Microsoft
      Windows
        CurrentVersion
          Explorer
            AutoplayHandlers
              EventHandlers
                ShowPicturesOnArrival               
                  AnotherEventHandler [REG_SZ] = 
                  SpikeAutoplay [REG_SZ] =
                  YetAnotherEventHandler [REG_SZ] =
```

Details on some of the event handlers can be found [here](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/hh127449(v=vs.85).aspx). A source of general understanding of this topic to me - even though it mislead me to implement IDropTarget - was [this msdn article](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/cc144212(v=vs.85).aspx).